# How do I integrate multiple choropleth maps made with Leaflet in Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet, choropleth

I have created three separate choropleth maps in Leaflet, all are across Europe with the same countries being used. Each choropleth map shows a different type of ratio and has two layers for 1999 and 2009.

Whilst I have successfully integrated the choropleth maps individually to Shiny with the year layers, I want to be able to just have one Shiny map with a drop down bar to click between the three different choropleth maps, whilst still keeping my layers for each map.

Can anyone suggest how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a leafletProxy for that. I slightly modified the example from [here](https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/shiny.html) to better suit what you are asking for. Hope this helps!

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)

ui <- bootstrapPage(
  tags$style(type = "text/css", "html, body {width:100%;height:100%}"),
  leafletOutput("map", width = "100%", height = "100%"),
  absolutePanel(top = 10, right = 10,
                selectInput("maptype", "Map type: ",
                            choices = c("map 1", "map 2", "map 3")
                )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  # Reactive expression for the data subsetted to what the user selected
  filteredData <- reactive({
    if(input$maptype=="map 1") return(quakes[sample(1:nrow(quakes),50,replace=TRUE),])
    if(input$maptype=="map 2") return(head(quakes,50))
    if(input$maptype=="map 3") return(tail(quakes,50))

  })


  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet(quakes) %>% addTiles() %>%
      fitBounds(~min(long), ~min(lat), ~max(long), ~max(lat))
  })

  observe({
    leafletProxy("map", data = filteredData()) %>%
      clearShapes() %>%
      addCircles(radius = ~10^mag/10, weight = 1, color = "#777777", fillOpacity = 0.7, popup = ~paste(mag)
      )
  })


}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, whilst it has helped me to get closer to what I was trying to achieve, and there is now a drop down list, a lot of errors occur and the map itself doesn't load at all?

I am certain that this is because I am not replacing my own information correctly into the code you have suggested..

My data frame is laid out as .. a country name, dependancy ratio A 1999, dependancy ratio A 2009, dependancy ratio B 1999, dependancy ratio B 2009 etc.. for all three dependancy ratios.. In the section for filtered data, I think this is  where I am entering the wrong code?

Comment: Below is what I have written using my Europe data frame... Apologies I am very knew to Shiny.

# Reactive expression for the data subsetted to what the user selected
  filteredData <- reactive({
    if(input$maptype=="mymap") return(Europe[sample(1:nrow(Europe),50,replace=TRUE),])
    if(input$maptype=="mymap.1") return(head(Europe),50))
    if(input$maptype=="mymap.2") return(tail(Europe,50))
  })

Comment: Hi Emily. Please consider posting this as a new question, I am happy to help. Try and make a minimal example using [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/shiny/10653/how-to-write-mcve-minimal-complete-and-verifiable-example-shiny-apps#t=201707241720253304179). So make sure you include your (stripped-down) shiny code and some actual data, so I can reproduce your errors.

Comment: Hi @Florian, Would you mind me emailing you? I am not able to post the data online. Thanks for your help.

Comment: That's alright, I'll see if I can help you find the issue.